# Change strings from one string to another in an array based on a condition

Tags: c#

I have an array of strings, most of which are string values "true" or "false", there are other strings there but i don't wish to alter them.

So i wish to loop through the strings and where i encounter the word "true" or "false" i want to change the string to "1" or "0"

These strings of 1, 0 and others will end up being used as parameters passed to a SQL stored procedure IE: seCmd.Parameters["@CheckListRef"].Value = data[0];

I am merely struggling with the syntax and therefore seeking guidence

```
string[] data = args.Trim().Split(',');

// Loop over strings
foreach (string s in data)
{
    if(s == "true")
    {
        convert the string True to the string 1
    }
    else if(s == "false")
    {
      convert the string True to the string 0
    }
}
```

please can someone offer some guidance

Comment: it may be worth providing an example of the args you are passing as well as what you eventually hope to do with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

```
   string[] data = args.Trim().Split(',');

    for(int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        if(data[i] == "true")
        {
            data[i] = "1";
        }
        else if(data[i] == "false")
        {
            data[i] = "0";
        }
    }
```

Also, you could shorten your code a bit by doing the following:

```
   string[] data = args.Trim().Split(',');

    for(int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        data[i].Replace("true", "0").Replace("false", "1");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

What your code is missing is a reference back to the array location you are checking.

Using a `for` loop would let you keep that reference:

```
string[] data = args.Trim().Split(',');

// Loop over strings
for(int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    if(data[i] == "true")
    {
        data[i] = "1";
    }
    else if(data[i] == "false")
    {
        data[i] = "0";
    }
}
```

Note - the above is case sensitive, so you may wan to replace the string tests with `data[i].Equals("true", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is LINQ version which will return you a new array:

```
string[] newData = data.Select(r => (r == "true" ? "1" : r == "false" ? "0" : r))
                        .ToArray();
```

Or if you want to ignore case then:

```
newData = data.Select(r => 
           (r.Equals("true", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? "1" 
           :r.Equals("false", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? "0" 
           : r))
           .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

**You do not have to convert it to `1 or 0`**. Simply do `Convert.ToBoolean()` if your datatype is `bit` then try this:

```
bool bln;
if(bool.TryParse(data[0], out bln))
 {
   seCmd.Parameters.Add("@CheckListRef",SqlDbType.Bit).Value =bln;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a for loop for this but, in your case would this not work

```
if(s == "true")
{
    s="1";
}
else if(s == "false")
{
  s="0";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go for a LINQ expression:

```
var parsedData = data.Trim()
.Where(d => d == "true" || d == "false")
.Select(d => bool.Parse(d) ? "1" : "0")
.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string originalString = "true, True, FALSE,  something true,false,something else,false";
string resultString = Regex.Replace(
                originalString, @"((?<=(,\s*))|^)true((?=(\s*,))|$)", "1",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
resultString = Regex.Replace(
                resultString, @"((?<=(,\s*))|^)false((?=(\s*,))|$)", "0", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string[] resultArray = Regex.Split(resultString, @"\s*,\s*");
```

resultArray:

```
 1
 1
 0
 something true
 0
 something else
 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = args.Trim()
               .Split(',')
               .ToList()
               .ConvertAll(s => s.Replace("true", "1").Replace("false", "0"));
```